# How to stop PHP service without stoping web-server service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apache2

PHP can be stop by stopping the web-server service.

e.g.

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

or

```
# apache2ctl stop
```

Would it be possible to stop PHP alone without disrupting apache2 service?

Answer (score 2):

When PHP is running as a standalone service, `php-fpm`, you can stop it separately.

When PHP is running as an Apache module, you can't.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Schneider. Here are 2 links on installing LAMP on Ubuntu. I should follow the 2nd link in order to have standalone PHP service right?

1. https://tecadmin.net/install-lamp-ubuntu-20-04/

2. https://tecadmin.net/setup-apache-php-fpm-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 0):

remove module loading at apache configuration and restart apache.

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: comment out php related configuration in httpd.conf    "LoadModule php7_module modules/mod_php.so"